# Count occurence of multiple numbers in vector one by one

Tags: r, counting

I have two vectors

```
a <- c(1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2)
b <- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

I want to know how many times each element in b occurs in a. So the result should be

```
c(3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0)
```

All methods I found like `match()`,`==`, `%in%` etc. are not suited for entire vectors. I know I can use a loop over all elements in b,

```
for (i in 1:length(b)) {
    c[I] <- sum(a==b, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

but this is used often and takes to long. That's why I'm looking for a vectorized way, or a way to use `apply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `factor` and `table`

```
table(factor(a, unique(b)))
#
#1 2 3 4 5 6
#3 3 2 1 2 0
```

---

Since you mentioned `match`, here is a possibility without `sapply` loop (thanks to @thelatemail)

```
table(factor(match(a, b), unique(b)))
#
#1 2 3 4 5 6
#3 3 2 1 2 0
```

Comment: You could avoid the `sapply` too I think and fall back to `match`'s vectorised code - `table(factor(b[match(a,b)], levels=unique(b)))`

Comment: @thelatemail Hmm, I think you're right; but then wouldn't `table(factor(a, unique(b)))` be even shorter?

Comment: Well, yeah, but I wasn't bright enough to think of that. ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail That's definitely not giving yourself enough credit! I had looked at `match(a, b)` but failed to make the connection you made. Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: The version in the edit resulted in a great reduction in computing time, even compared to sapply.

Comment: @Hope Yes, that's as expected I guess. Recasting as a `factor` plus `table` will be  very quick, since you're avoiding both `sapply` (an optimised loop, but still a loop) and `match` (or `which`).

Comment: @Hope It might be even faster to do `tabulate(factor(a, unique(b)))`. `table` internally calls `tabulate` to do the actual counting; the rest in `table` is error checking, handling of additional function arguments, etc.

Comment: Yes it is. Note however, that the output from this method does not give the 0 for counting 6 at the end. When it is needed, these need to be added later. (That doen't consume more time than tabulate takes though.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option, using `sapply` with `which`:

```
a <- c(1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

sapply(b, function(x) length(which(a == x)))
[1] 3 3 2 1 2 0
```

### Demo

Comment: Of the methods so far this one is the fastest. It works faster with length(width( )), than with sum( ).
All Methods work. Thank you everyone for the quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorised method

```
x = expand.grid(b,a)
rowSums( matrix(x$Var1 == x$Var2, nrow = length(b)))
# [1] 3 3 2 1 2 0
```