# Count elements from a vector with also zero frequencies in r

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have a vector with characters like this:

```
v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

and I want to count the frequencies of every character in another vector i.e.:

```
v2 <- c("B", "B", "C", "D", "C")
```

the output should be like this:

```
A B C D E
0 2 2 1 0
```

I've tried with `table()`, `merge()`, and using `%in%`, but I can't get an output with also the zero frequencies of the characters which are not in the vector that I'm examining.

Comment: Is this part of a course or something? We had this near identical question the other day - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980513/count-occurence-of-multiple-numbers-in-vector-one-by-one ?

Comment: @thelatemail well, I’m a student, but I don’t know if these two answers are related. I’m sorry this question is a duplicate.

Comment: It's not a big issue - it's just that sometimes there are a flood of identical questions from an online course. It's nice to know if that's the case so a good duplicate answer can be identified so everyone is happy. (e.g. take a search here for `[r] pollutantmean` and see the Coursera questions by the dozens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `table` after converting 'v2' to `factor` with `levels` specified as 'v1'

```
table(factor(v2, levels = v1))
# A B C D E 
# 0 2 2 1 0
```

Comment: Great, thank you. So, when operating on characters and string it’s useful to use factors.

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of `sum` with `TRUE/FALSE` vectors

```
sapply(v1, function(x) sum(x==v2))
# A B C D E 
# 0 2 2 1 0
```